# Is there a way to format my c++ code using one key ";" in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, formatting

I want to format my code when I end my line of code with `;`, like in Visual studio.
I tried to make a hotkey binding for the `;` to save the file but I couldn't writ the `;` in my code again?
Is there a way to do that?

This is my `json` settings for the `;` key.

```
    {
        "key": ";",
        "command": "editor.action.file.save"
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the `type` command

```json
{
  "key": ";",
  "command": "runCommands",
  "args": {
    "commands": [
      { "command": "type",
        "args": { "text": ";" }
      },
      "editor.action.file.save"
    ]
  },
  "when": "editorTextFocus"
}
```